# How to 'refresh' React JS page after deleting item from Firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, refresh

ReactJS. I have a list populated from a firebase db.

I have a delete button that finds the last entry from a certain user, and deletes that entry from the db.

However, the original list remains untouched on the screen. I need some sort of 'refresh' (Being React JS, maybe that is not the best word to use).

I have tried creating a refresh() function, and this does send the updated list from the db, however, this new list is added to the bottom of the old list, which should be replaced.

EDIT: In writing this question out, I realised what I needed to do! I'll leave what I did here for future React JS newbies such as myself...

The onDelete function is called on clicking a delete button...

```
// DELETE LAST USER COMMENT 
  onDelete = () => {
    //  delete last message code he
    let userName = this.state.name;
    console.log(userName);
    messageRef.orderByChild('name').equalTo(userName).limitToLast(1).once('child_added', function (snapshot) {
      snapshot.ref.remove();
    })
    this.refresh()
  }

  refresh = () => {
    const previousMessages = [];
    messageRef.on('child_added', snapshot => {
      previousMessages.push({
        id: snapshot.key,
        message: snapshot.val().text,
        name: snapshot.val().name
      })
      this.setState({
        list: previousMessages
      })
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I made the refresh() as a direct copy of my ComponentDidMount() function. However, I needed to empty the declared `const previousMessages = [];` array instead of leaving it as `const previousMessages = this.state.list;` in ComponentDidMount().